# Using autoresizing mask on uicollectionview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to support rotation on UICollectionview such that when device is rotated - the collectionview will expand to fill the bounds of the containing view

```
self.collectionView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

But when the device is rotated the cells move around because of the new collectionview frame.

Is there way to make sure that they have flexible margins - in order to mimick the stock iphone app when rotating the device  -

In the stock app the cells rotate around the central axis of the screen and expand very smoothly.

Comment: Maybe you should re-compute your layout when view rotates ? if layout insets (margins) are defined in fraction of `UICollectionView` bounds, a single call to 'invalidateLayout' might work.

Comment: use the reveal app to debug what happen with you views when rotating. I have used it and it's very useful http://revealapp.com/